# PHP mysqli unable to pass id to new php page

Tags: php, html

Displaying of records with bookid, title, author with hyperlink ref on Title. I need to pass Book id as a parameter to new page

Part of the program

```
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        echo "<table style='width:100%'>";
        echo '<th>ID</th>'.'<th>Title</th>'.'<th>Author</th>'.'<th>Price</th>';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo "<td bgcolor='mistyrose'>{$row['BookID']} </td> "
             . "<a href='displayIndividual.php?".$row['BookID']."'><td bgcolor='mistyrose'>" . $row['Title'] . "</td>"
             . "<td bgcolor='mistyrose'>{$row['Author']} </td>"
             . "<td bgcolor='mistyrose'>{$row['Price']} </td>";
            echo '</tr>';
        }
```

I have given hypelink for title and passing Book id

The hyperlink is working fine. On the new page I think it is not passing the value.

On the second page: This is the program getting called from the first program.

after id%20 I don't see the actual value? Is it ok?
http://localhost/Pgpproject319thaug/PhpProject1/displayIndividual.php?id%20=

Also, I am getting an error on line 8 on trying to get the variable name. I cannot see where the mistake is.

Why am I not able to assign the variable using _GET?

Line 8  is

> Notice: Undefined variable: _Get in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pgpproject319thaug\PhpProject1\displayIndividual.php on line 8

The actual program is only one line to see whether we can pass the value

```
$BookID = $_Get['BookID'];
echo $BookID;
```

Comment: You pass a parameter, but give the value no name. change to something like `'displayIndividual.php?BookID=".$row['BookID']."`.

Comment: Share the code file completely, It is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that stand out:

First, when you're `echo`-ing the actual line that prints the hyperlink, you're appending the ID directly after the filename: `"<a href='displayIndividual.php?".$row['BookID']."'>"`. So instead of generating links with the IDs assigned to a named `GET` parameter, you just get something like `displayIndividual.php?123` when what you want is `displayIndividual.php?id=123` (you see how there's an `id=` in between the link and the actual ID?).

Next, in `displayIndividual.php`, based on the error message, you're using `$_Get` instead of `$_GET`.